# cannot get the constants defined in index.php in the included files

Tags: php, constants

here's my index.php file

```
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors','On');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
define ('EXT','.php');



$url = $_GET['url'];
```

I am really puzzled. How do i solve it.

```
require_once(ROOT . DS .'doctrine_bootstrap.php' );
require_once (ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . 'bootstrap.php');
```

my problem is I cannot get the constants `ROOT` and `DS` in the included file `doctrine_bootstrap.php`;

MY doctrine_bootstrap.php is as follows

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array(ROOT . DS . 'src' . DS . 'models' );
$isDevMode = true;
```

//  the connection configuration

```
 $dbParams = array(
 'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
 'user'     => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname'   => 'adserver_db',
```

);

```
 $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
 $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Edit: I seem to get the constants in `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: Hm, if you're in a namespace there... do `\ROOT` & `\DS` work?

Comment: @Wriken no it doesnot

Comment: If that does not work.. does your `index.php` define a namespace?

Comment: no it doesnot define a namespace

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [namespace problem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.innamespace).

You should try to access your constants like `\DS`, etc.

Comment: I tried using \DS but now it just gives a fatal error undefined constant DS in the file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could use the namespaces like that. It should be as \DS,\Root.